# How to transform JSON object to another in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I want to convert my `JSON` to a specific format but not sure what is the best way. I want to make a generic function which I can use commonly. I do not want some code which has hard coded value such as `root`, `Amount`, etc.

I am using `typeScript` and `node`.

**Current:**

```
{
    "elements": [
        {
            "type": "element",
            "name": "root",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "element",
                    "name": "Amount",
                    "elements": [
                        {
                            "type": "text",
                            "text": "1.00"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "element",
                    "name": "Discount",
                    "elements": [
                        {
                            "type": "text",
                            "text": "0.00"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Expected:**

```
{
  "root": {
    "Amount": "1.00",
    "Discount": "0.00"
  }
}
```

**Attempt-1:** .  This is not neat approach. So I do not like it.

```
var newJsonData = convertedXml2json
  .replace(/"elements": /g, "")
  .replace(/"type": "element",/g, "")
  .replace(/"name":/g, "")
  .replace(/"type": "text",/g, "")
  .replace(/"text":/g, "")
  .replace("[", "")
  .replace("{", "");
console.log(newJsonData);
```

**Attempt-2:** This comes as `null`

```
var len = convertedXml2json.elements,
    newData = {updatedJson:[]},
    i;

for ( i=0; i < len; i+=1 ) {
    newData.updatedJson.push(  [ convertedXml2json.elements[ i ].name, convertedXml2json.elements[ i ].elements[i].text] );
}
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far and explain what what went wrong with your current attempt (errors, unexpected results, etc.).

Comment: @p.s.w.g, I have updated question with my attempts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you already have the JSON parsed into an object, you can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) along with [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to convert the result back to an object:

```js
const input = {
  "elements": [{
    "type": "element",
    "name": "root",
    "elements": [{
        "type": "element",
        "name": "Amount",
        "elements": [{
          "type": "text",
          "text": "1.00"
        }]
      },
      {
        "type": "element",
        "name": "Discount",
        "elements": [{
          "type": "text",
          "text": "0.00"
        }]
      }
    ]
  }]
};
const output = Object.fromEntries(input
  .elements.map(x => [x.name, Object.fromEntries(x
    .elements.map(y => [y.name, y.elements[0].text]))]));
console.log(output);
```

Alternatively, you could do this [lodash's](https://lodash.com) `map` and `fromPairs`:

```js
// import _ from 'lodash'; 

const input = {
  "elements": [{
    "type": "element",
    "name": "root",
    "elements": [{
        "type": "element",
        "name": "Amount",
        "elements": [{
          "type": "text",
          "text": "1.00"
        }]
      },
      {
        "type": "element",
        "name": "Discount",
        "elements": [{
          "type": "text",
          "text": "0.00"
        }]
      }
    ]
  }]
};
const output = _.fromPairs(
  _.map(input.elements, x => [x.name, _.fromPairs(
    _.map(x.elements, y => [y.name, y.elements[0].text]))]));
console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am getting `TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function` error. Do I need to install any `npm` for this?

Comment: @CSharper Hmm, it appears NodeJS doesn't support `Object.fromEntries` yet. You could use a [polyfill like this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object.fromentries). Otherwise, you could use a library like [lodash](http://lodash.com/), see my updated answer.

Comment: `lodash` option worked for me. I just had to install `https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash` and this worked like a charm. Thank you.